# Django overwrite header value in request object

Tags: django

I am writing middleware that, when it receives a request containing a header 'Foo', modifies its value, before passing the request on.

Django makes direct assignment illegal, so these do not work:

```
request.headers['Foo'] = 'bar'
request['Foo'] = 'bar'
```

I do have a working solution, but it's a bit hacky:

```
request.headers.__dict__['_store']['foo']=('Foo','bar')
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing it that I've missed?

Comment: You can use `new_request = request.headers.copy()`, and then modify the new request params.

Comment: `request.headers` is a better way to access the headers that are contained in `request.META`. But it's read-only. So in fact, just modify `request.META['HTTP_FOO']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTTP headers are contained in `request.META` which is just a dictionary that you can read **and write**. In `META` the header names are prefixed with `HTTP_` and uppercase. So to access the header 'Foo' you'd do:

```
request.META['HTTP_FOO'] = 'bar'
```

The `headers` property (cached property in fact) is just a convenient way to access the HTTP headers without having to worry about the prefix and uppercasing, but it's read-only.

To reset a cached property, just remove it from the instance's `__dict__` like so:

```
request.__dict__.pop('headers', None)
```

This will make sure the method is called again next time it's accessed. I added `None` to the `pop()` to ensure this doesn't crash, since if it wasn't accessed, it won't be in `__dict__`. If you access it explicitly in your own code, then `request.__dict__.pop('headers')` is sufficient.

Comment: This didn't work. It does indeed update the request.META dict, but it does not update the output of request.headers.

Comment: `headers` is a `@cached_property` so if it was accessed before you made the assignment, it wouldn't reflect the change.

Comment: Yes, it is accessed. I read the original value, process it, and then overwrite the original value with the processed value.

Comment: Then don't read the original value using `headers`. Use `META`. And make sure no middleware that comes before yours accesses `headers`. Your middleware should be probably right at the top.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I need middleware above this, so this solution seems very fragile. I guess I could do the thing I posted in the question, and also update the META dict for completeness. I know it's not pretty, but will it cause any problems?

Comment: Why do you need to change headers in the first place? Sounds like there are many alternatives that could serve the same purpose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210681/discussion-between-alex-and-dirkgroten).